# Function pipeline how to skip process block? Similar to continue in a foreach loop

Tags: powershell

I'm working on a function to accept pipeline input of multiple objects.

I want to be able to skip the processing of an object if the Property matches certain criteria; similar to using "Continue" in a foreach loop. I realize that I could use switch/If statements but I'm trying to find if there's a way to just skip that object altogether.
The simple code below shows more or less what I'm trying to accomplish

```
Function Get-Foobar{
 Param (
    [parameter(ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName)][string]$Item
 )

    Begin{ 
    # DO SOME INIT STUFF
    }

    Process{
        If($Item -ne "Foobar") { 
        #SOMEHOW SKIP THE PROCESS BLOCK#
        # CONTINUE? BREAK? RETURN? WHAT?
        } 
        Else{
            Write-host "Item was $($Item)"
        }

        #Continue doing stuff here.
        Write-host "Evertying was totally $Item"

    }
    End {
    # DO CLEAN UP STUFF
     }
}

$test = @([pscustomobject]@{Item = "Foobar"},[pscustomobject]@{Item = "NotFubar"} )


$test |Get-Foobar

Item was Foobar
Evertying was totally Foobar
Evertying was totally NotFubar <---- liked to skip this without having it in the upper if/Else
```

Comment: simply do `If($Item -eq "Foobar") { #do your stuff here }` and forget about the `else{..}`

Comment: call `return` in the `process` block if you want to skip to the next input item

Comment: @Theo that was only relevant to the sample code. The real production code was not that simple and I wanted to have a simple way to skip lots of code. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `Process` block is a self-contained scriptblock, so `continue` won't affect it.

Use `return` inside `process` to skip to the next input item in the pipeline:

```
function Get-Foobar {
    param(
        [Parameter(ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName = $true)]
        [string]$Item
    )

    Begin { 
        # DO SOME INIT STUFF
    }

    Process {
        if ($Item -ne "Foobar") { 
            # skip it!
            return
        }
        else {
            Write-host "Item was $($Item)"
        }

        #Continue doing stuff here.
        Write-host "Evertying was totally $Item"

    }
    End {
        # DO CLEAN UP STUFF
    }
}
```

Comment: This worked in my tests. thanks. I always forget that Return in Powershell is not like other languages I've used.

Comment: I mean, it returns control to the caller like in most other languages ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: Not an expert but I've found several such comments about the return statement in powershell. For me I started with PHP where return leaves the function to return a value.
Example: https://dille.name/blog/2016/02/04/careful-when-using-return-in-advanced-powershell-functions/

Comment: return for the win in the process block.  I just learned this, as I had been using try/catch and in the catch if the specific non-issue was the one, I would use 'continue', but that was killing my entire process block.  'Return', in the process block (rather than throwing into the catch) works perfectly.

Comment: It's funny, I stepped away, and then re-learned this, again from this Bing search result:).  Twice I've been saved here.

Comment: @JeremyBradshaw Haha, happy to hear you're getting some value out of it!